# RapidMiner 5.2 Converting Numeric to Nominal and Reverse

Tags: rapidminer

I am Clustering bunch of words with k-means algorithm in RapidMiner 5.2
I am converting nominal to numerical before the clustering. However, to really view my clustering, i need to view numbers back as word. How can i convert it back?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Parse Numbers` or `Guess Types` operators.